# web deferred image fail to load

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap-3, deferred-loading

I am newbie in web development and I'm having diffuculties making my web fast to load.

So I [found this article](https://varvy.com/pagespeed/defer-images.html) and I implemented it. When visualizing my page I get that the image is not rendered at all. I get the following image:

[image]

### Image html

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAD/ACwAAAAAAQABAAACADs=" data-src="~/images/menunavegacion.png" />
```

### Script

```
<script>
    function init() {
        var imgDefer = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
        for (var i = 0; i < imgDefer.length; i++) {
            if (imgDefer[i].getAttribute('data-src')) {
                imgDefer[i].setAttribute('src', imgDefer[i].getAttribute('data-src'));
            }
        }
    }
    window.onload = init;
</script>
```

### Debug info

Also, I debug it with chrome and it seems to be switching correctly the real image with the fake one. However the web do not load the proper one.

[image]

What am I missing?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you set the image path in the `src` attribute to `~/images/img.png`, asp.net will resolve the path and generate an url relative to the application base url: `/app_path/images/img.png`.

However the value of the attribute `data-src` is not processed and looks like `~/images/img.png` (still prefixed by `~`). When you replace the value of `src` by the value of `data-src`, the browser resolve the path of the image as `http://sample.com/~/images/img.png`. This path may not exists on your server and you get an error 404.

To sum up, you need to remove the `~` by using the method [`ResolveUrl`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.resolveurl.aspx) in WebForms or [`Url.Content`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.content.aspx) in MVC.

Comment: where should I use url.Content? in script? I tried but it does not seems to work

Comment: Done! using Razor. Thanks very much!